# question about the convergence of a function

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'll start off with what I know:

I know that if I have two functions f(x) and g(x)

if:
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x) < \int_0^\infty g(x)
$$

If g(x) converges as the values function approaches infinity, I know that f(x) also converges.

Here's my question:

If f(x) < g(x), and f(x) does not converge, does that mean that g(x) also does not converge?

Comment: you can find more info here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test

Comment: You will need conditions. For example suppose $f$ is allowed to be negative. Then $f$ could be bad and $g$ good.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. Technically, you are absolutely right! I think though that the OP is referring to the Comparison Theorem for improper integrals, where both functions are in the first quadrant :)

Comment: It could be a "trick" question. Or perhaps OP has not given the actual exact wording of the question.

Comment: Yes this is for a calc 2 class, and we're considering functions in the first quadrant, like e^-x from 0 to infinity and the like

Comment: Yeah, that may be true...

Comment: @ScubaSteve. If this is for a Calc 2 class, then I am confident about what I wrote in my answer below. May I know what textbook you are using?

Comment: We're using Calculus, Concepts and Contexts by Stewart

Comment: I wasn't really asking because the question I was working on was asking. Rather I was solving a question using that logic, and I wanted to make sure I wasn't off base for some reason I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ converges, you don't know anything about $g(x)$
If $f(x)$ diverges, then certainly $g(x)$ diverges